# How to categorize a range of values into a standardized range of values?

Tags: sql

For every row in my table, I have a range of numbers associated. For instance, in row #1 -- it has a a range of 1-5 in one the 'range' column.

What I'm trying to do is map that 'range' into a standardized bucket. So, the standardized buckets have ranges of 0-3, 3-7, etc... So, based on the range being from 1-5, I want SQL to return 0-3 as the standardized range.

Input Row:

```
Col1    Col2    
John    6-12
```

Expected Outcome:

```
Col1         Col2      Standardized Col3   
John         6-12           7-15
```

I'm at a loss for how to code this in SQL -- can anyone help?

Comment: I suggest expanding your question to show the input rows and the expected output.

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data, desired results, and tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case

```
select case range
         when betweeen 0 and 3 then  1
         when between  4 and 7 then 2
         else 3
       end
from my_table
```

or

```
select Col1,  Col2,  case range
         when '1-5' then   '0-3'
         when  '6-12' then '7-15'
         else  '16-22'
       end as Standardized  
from my_table
```

Comment: The problem isn't as black/white as that though. For example, if one row has the range (6-12) and the options for standardized buckets are 0-3, 3-7, and 7-12 -- I would want that row to return 7-12 as the standardized range based on most overlap.

Comment: explain better you question add  proper data sample  and the expected result  .

Comment: I added data sample in the question

Comment: @LawrenceChun   col2 is a string ?